# Connect Rotary Encoder with Python via Arduino

Tags: python-2.7, arduino

For a project I am working on I need to connect a rotary encoder to my Arduino Mega(2560) board. The rotary encoder will act as a sort of very precise scrolling wheel to position an object in my python code. I found this Arduino code which does very nicely what I want. However, in order to implenemt the encoder readout in python I somehow need to "connect" my Input I recieve from the Arduino board to my Python Code. I tried to somehow "convert" the Arduino code into Python code and came across the idependencies of **pySerial** and **pyfirmata** which looked promising. yet, there are certain functions in the Arduino that are not mimicked by Python, such as the `attachInterrupt()` function or `volatile unsigned int`.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction of to convert the following Arduino code for the rotary encoder into Python code.

```
// Encoder connect to digitalpin 2 and 3 on the Arduino.

volatile unsigned int counter = 0;  //This variable will increase or decrease depending on the rotation of encoder

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  //Setting up interrupt
  //A rising pulse from encodenren activated ai0(). AttachInterrupt 0 is DigitalPin nr 2 on moust Arduino.
  attachInterrupt(0, ai0, RISING);

  //B rising pulse from encodenren activated ai1(). AttachInterrupt 1 is DigitalPin nr 3 on moust Arduino.
  attachInterrupt(1, ai1, RISING);
}

void loop() {
  // Send the value of counter
  Serial.println (counter);
} 

void ai0() {
  // ai0 is activated if DigitalPin nr 2 is going from LOW to HIGH
  // Check pin 3 to determine the direction
  if(digitalRead(3)==LOW) {
    counter++;
  }else{
    counter--;
  }
}

void ai1() {
  // ai0 is activated if DigitalPin nr 3 is going from LOW to HIGH
  // Check with pin 2 to determine the direction
  if(digitalRead(2)==LOW) {
    counter--;
  }else{
    counter++;
  }
}
```

created 2014
by Ben-Tommy Eriksen
https://github.com/BenTommyE/BenRotaryEncoder

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to convert this code? Arduino alreaqdy sends a value of counter, so you can just receive it and do whatever you want with that value.

Comment: So far I have understood, if I upload this code to the Arduino it will constantly use the port  to access the data. The Arduino will later be connected to other things that require an input signal from Python. However, I won't be able to access the Arduino board with Python as long as I am getting input from the Arduino. If I try I always get the error message: `SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')`. According to some google research and on this site, I get it because the port is already in use by the file sending the counter to the PC.

Comment: How do you connect to Arduino? From Python script, or from Arduino monitor? You can have only one application opening a port a a time. And I mean PC side - Arduino has to have a port open all the time, and it can both read and write to it the same time.

Comment: So far I've uploaded the "standardFirmata" script from the arduino examples to the board and try to call it with the functions of the `pyfirmata` and `serial` libraries from python. Yet, at the moment it only returns "None" for both pins instead of 0 or 1...

Comment: No! Don't do the pulse processing on a PC. It won't work - the pulses from encoder have to high frequency to be sent to a PC. Besides Arduino is really good in doing real time processing which will be required for that. Just send a counter value to a PC, just like you have in the example.

Comment: But then, how do I transfer the counter value I see on the serial monitor into my Python code to implement the changes of the rotary encoder ? The idea is that the turning of the rotary encoder moves an object in my python code (like a scroll wheel) and if the object reaches a certain position I need to send a signal to a valve (which is also connected to the Arduino board) to open. But while the rotary encoder uses the port to stream the counter to my PC I can't use it to send the signal to open the valve, right ?

Comment: I think you should do some serious reading on serial communication. It is two way (so you can both read the counter and send whatever necessary to Arduino). And you don't "transfer" anything from serial monitor, because you don't open it - only one application can talk on the same port at a time, so either your Python program or serial monitor. You already found pySerial, so why don't you start using it?